# How to use php to call information and post to another webpage

Tags: php, html, templates, web, call

I am making a website and have a pretty strong template that I have made. Of course, I need to make changes to it once and a while and would like to figure out a way to make changes to only one .php file rather than having to change 10+ different files. There has to be a way to do this in php, I just do not know where to look.

Comment: `figure out a way to make changes to only one .php file rather than having to change 10+ different files`. How? What common denominator do these files share? What are you trying to adjust? Only content? How are you going to edit them? Overwrite them? Appending to the file? Are you opposed to a database? What does the template structure look like?

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping. they are all php files.. I am only trying to adjust content, so i guess i would have one page that is my template.php then I would want to call that on all of the other pages then just change the content section 


check out domdit.tk/rgc I think you will get what I mean..

btw, this is a client website and i am not sensuous mystic

Comment: Do you mean simply changing something like header information?

Comment: @nomistic yeah, I just want to be able to call the header and the sidebar on all the other pages instead of copy and pasting a ton of code then changing it for every page.. I just want to change the white area you see on this page, domdit.tk/rgc

**this is a client's site, I am not sensuous mystic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a separate file which you can use as an include file in your scripts.

for instance, here a header script:

```
<?php

   $title = 'this is the title';

?>
```

and name it something like header.php

Then all you need to do is to put something like this in each page that has the updates:

```
include_once('header.php');
```

Comment: Style point: the brackets are not necessary. [From the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): "_Because `include` is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument_".

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using htaccess,
make rewrite rule like this

make index.php with your template
and blank file demo.php

`RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^Demo$ index.php?page=demo.php`

and put this code in your body part of index.php file

```
$page = isset ( $_REQUEST [ 'page' ] ) ? $_REQUEST [ 'page' ] : 'home' ;
if ( $page !== 'home' && strlen ( $page ) > 0 ) {
     $file = sprintf ( '%s' , $page ) ;
     if ( file_exists ( $file ) ) {
            require_once $file ;
     };
} else require_once 'default page you wanna show' ;
```

and brows to www.yoursite/Demo

you will redirect to demo.php with your theme